# Examine tif file contents Windows vs Linux

Tags: avi, tiff

I am using Graphicsmagick with tif files, to create many that are then turned into a .avi by *MakeAVI.exe* in *Windows 7*

**success:** In Linux generate a base image > 1920x1080 with solid black background with image on left side, followed by `gm composite -gravity East` to get more content into each frame; then use MakeAVI in Windows to generate a cropped 30fps avi down to 1920x1080.

**fail:** In Windows Paint generate a base image @ 1920x1080 with solid back background; use this at step 1 using `gm composite -gravity West` to create my frames; using MakeAVI it simply says cannot read  .tif files.

I believe I have narrowed down the problem to whatever Microsoft Windows 7 is doing in how it saves a binary .tif as opposed to how the .tif's are exported  from the proprietary software package I am using in Linux and how GraphicsMagick saves .tif's.

How (in Linux) do I compare two binary .tif files to figure out what the problem is?  I can open and view the *fail makeavi* tif files anywhere, they just can't be opened by *MakeAVI.exe*

Comment: and i just realized a black-1920x1080.tif saved from windows is 8KB, but a linux one is 13MB ?

Comment: TIF is a very complicated format with many sub-formats.  Is there a reason that you have to use TIF?  The typical reason for TIF is lossless compression with multi-page tagging.  If you don't need multi-page, you might try PNG instead.

Comment: the software program i'm using to manipulate a model exports only in tif so that's what I start with.  would it be more robust then up front to convert all exported tif's to what then?  Then I can do my graphicmagick composites ending up with N files of ? format to feed MakeAVI?

Comment: Makeavi can use bmp, png, jpg, tif...maybe others. No gif

Comment: I'd go from tiff to png, if it were me.

Comment: thanks.  I did find out with `gm convert -identify` that it listed three items from my original `black-1920-1080.tif`, I apparently exported it as such unknowingly; output of identify listed `black-1920x1080-1.tif` with 1920x1080 resolution then it listed `black-1920x1080-2.tif` as some other resolution, and then `black-1920x1080-3.tif` as some other resolution.